# How to create a crossed out calligraphic S?

Tags: symbols

I’m looking for how to write in latex these two symbols:
[image: Calligraphic S]
[image: Bar calligraphic S]

The first one is from `\mathcal{S}`, or this would be fine. But how about the second one? For sure, it is not from the cancel package???

Therefore, my question is: how to do such a little horizontal bar on the second S?

Thank you very much for all your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\strokeS{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{1.6\LMpt}{%
  \SavedStyle\mathcal{S}}{\rule{3\LMpt}{.6\LMpt}\mkern.7mu}{O}{r}{F}{F}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{S}\strokeS_{\strokeS_{\strokeS}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That’s exactly what I wanted!!! Many thanks

Answer (score 8):

This should be something like you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\crosscalS}{{\mathcal{S}\mathpalette\crosscal@S\relax}}
\newcommand{\crosscal@S}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{$\m@th#1\textnormal{-}\mkern-0.3mu$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{S}\crosscalS\mathcal{S}$

$\mathcal{S}\mathcal{S}\mathcal{S}$ % check for the width

$X_{\mathcal{S}}X_{\crosscalS}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @campa Yes, it is a remainder of an earlier attempt. I'll fix.

Comment: 7-1...I'm not "feeling the love" on this question. LOL.

Comment: Finally, I'm feeling the love.